# Customizing UISlider thumb icon: How to stop thumb icon from reverting back to default circle icon when drag?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I want to customize the thumb of my UISlider to a rectangular icon I made. I've managed to do that somewhat. The problem is when I drag the UISlider it changes back to the default circle icon.

How can I set the thumb image so it always remains as the custom rectangular icon even when I drag it?

I've detailed my code and included a link so you can see what I'm talking about below.

```
class DrawViewController: UIViewController {    
    var heightSlider: UISlider = UISlider()        
    var fontColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.91, green:0.91, blue:0.91, alpha:1.0)
    var barButtonColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.03, green:0.25, blue:0.51, alpha:1.0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        heightSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 98, 31))
        heightSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = barButtonColor
        heightSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = fontColor
        heightSlider.thumbTintColor = barButtonColor
        heightSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "blueSliderThumbHeight")!, forState: .Normal)

        self.view.addSubview(heightSlider)
    } 
}
```

[To see my app/what I'm talking about](http://giphy.com/gifs/3o8dp25ajCIcJOleAU/html5)

Comment: weird, basically this code should run..... why don't you have an outlet like this: '@IBOutlet weak var progressSlider: UISlider!'

Comment: The code runs. The slider does display the custom rectangle thumb icon. But when I drag the slider, the thumb icon changes back to the default circle icon. I don't have an outlet b/c I'm programmatically creating the slider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just have to delete the line `heightSlider.thumbTintColor = barButtonColor`

```
class DrawViewController: UIViewController {    
    var heightSlider: UISlider = UISlider()        
    var fontColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.91, green:0.91, blue:0.91, alpha:1.0)
    var barButtonColor: UIColor = UIColor(red:0.03, green:0.25, blue:0.51, alpha:1.0)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        heightSlider = UISlider(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, 98, 31))
        heightSlider.minimumTrackTintColor = barButtonColor
        heightSlider.maximumTrackTintColor = fontColor
        heightSlider.thumbTintColor = barButtonColor //delete this line!
        heightSlider.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "blueSliderThumbHeight")!, forState: .Normal)

        self.view.addSubview(heightSlider)
    } 
}
```